# What is the correct specification for a segmented regression of interrupted time series data with a non-equivalent comparison group?

Tags: time-series, segmented-regression

I know this is the [general specification](http://heapol.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2011/01/27/heapol.czr004.full.pdf+html) for a single group:

$Y_i$ = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1$*time + $\beta_2$*post + $\beta_3$*timepost

where `time` is a continuous variable indicating the time (e.g., month) of every observation in the study; `post` is an indicator for whether the observation is after the introduction of the intervention; and `timepost` is time since the introduction of the intervention (0 if pre-intervention).

What is the correct specification for a segmented regression of interrupted time series data with a non-equivalent comparison group?